# How can I merge data back to SpatialPolygon (or retain initially) after nowrapRecenter command?

Tags: r, maptools

I am using `newobj <- nowrapRecenter(obj)`, from the package `maptools` to recenter a `SpatialPolygonsDataFrame` such that longitude runs `0 - 360` (pacific view) rather than `-180` to `180` (Atlantic view). Unfortunately, the resulting `newobj` is a `SpatialPolygon` only --- the data is lost. I expect I can merge the data back on, but I'm not sure how... generally I would merge by a data column, and this new polygon has no data.

I am using this GEOLEV1 shapefile:

https://international.ipums.org/international/gis_harmonized_1st.shtml

Answer (score 1):

Everything should be ordered so, it is probably as simple as coercing back to a SpatialPolygonsDataFrame object. Say y is the original data and x is the new SpatialPolygons object you could try: `new <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(x, y@data)`

Comment: Thanks! You're so right, that works perfectly. Thanks a ton, I really appreciate it. : )

Comment: @LeahBevis, if this answer was helpful to you, then upvote it. If it solved your question, then accept it (green checkmark under the vote arrows). See: https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers. Tks.